# Qtile: mouse_callbacks doesn't work inside the TextBox widget

Tags: python, widget, archlinux, window-managers

I'm new in qtile.

I'm trying to implement a clicckable widget but `mouse_callbacks` does not work inside the `TextBox` widget. What I'm not getting is why it works perfectly inside the `Volume` widget (example below).What am I missing? THX

```
widget.Volume(
              fmt = " VOL: {} ",
              mause_callbacks = lazy.spawn("amixer -q set Master toggle")
                ),

                
widget.TextBox(
              fmt = " MUTE ",
              background = "#0082FC",
              mause_callbacks = lazy.spawn("amixer -q set Master toggle"),
```

Answer (score 0):

- m**a**use_callbacks change to `mouse_callbacks`.
- use dict

```py
mouse_callbacks = {"Button1": lazy.spawn("amixer -q set Master toggle")}
```